# UdpDiscoveryEndpoint with a broadcast address

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, ws-discovery

Is it possible to use Wcf UdpDiscoveryEndpoint with a broadcast address instead of multicast ?
I tried using a broadcast address but that threw an exception, is it a limitation of WcfDiscovery ?

this is the exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpUtility.BindSocket(Socket socket, IPEndPoint localEndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpUtility.CreateListenSocket(IPAddress ipAddress, Int32& port, Int32 receiveBufferSize, Int32 timeToLive, Int32 interfaceIndex, Boolean allowMulticastLoopback, Boolean isLoopbackAdapter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpChannelListener.InitSockets(Boolean updateListenPort)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpChannelListener..ctor(IUdpTransportSettings settings, BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncodingBindingElement.InternalBuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem at a customer's server. It turned out that he had two network devices with overlapping subnet masks configured. Thus udpDiscoveryEndpoint could not start listening with the above exception.